# How to use AuthenticationProvider Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new in Spring and I need some help with authentication by using Spring Security. Also, if someone can, it would be good to make clear some moments, (I'll mark them by (#{1-..})) because there is a lot of "magic" and weird things for me in the beginning, even after tutorials and documentation reading =(.

So, I try to implement AuthenticationProvider and if I understand everything right in authenticate() method I can organize my specific authentication logic. 
So my code looks like:

( (#1)If I understand right, Spring automatically create bean with name value="customAuth" and there is no need to tell about this bean in any context file. Am I right?)
**CustomAuthenticationProvider**:

```
@Service(value = "customAuth")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{
    @Autowired
    public Storages storage;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String login = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    final User user = storage.uSM.findByAuthorization(login, password);
    if (user==null){
        return null;
    } else {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:/resources/spring-context.xml
        classpath:/resources/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/resources/spring-context.xml
        classpath:/resources/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secret/page</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
</web-app>
```

**spring-security.xml**:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secret/page" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <form-login
        login-page="/sign/in"
        default-target-url="/secret/page"
        authentication-failure-url="/sign/in"
        password-parameter="password"
        username-parameter="username"
    />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuth"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

The next one is my in.jsp file with my custom login form. As I read, this form will be sent to the /login on default (I know that we can change it by setting *login-processing-url*). The second one questions (#2) is about this "/login". As I can understand when we post our form to /login we send it to some created by Spring class which will manage it and give necessary data to AuthorizationProvider which we set here: `<authentication-provider ref="customAuth"/>`? Or I am wrong?
Anyway, it doesn't work. A have tried a lot of variants, but no one doesn't work. So here it is my **in.jsp**:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <c:if test="${failed==1}">  
        <font color="red">
        Authentication failed. Wrong email/password.
        </font>
    </c:if>

    <form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
        <label> E-mail </label>
        <input type="email" name="username" required><br>
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in"><br>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and **In.java** @Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/sign/in")
public class In {
    @RequestMapping (method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String showForm(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer failed, ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("failed", failed);
    return "sign/in";
    }
}
```

In this case, after I POST my form, it redirects me to /login and 404 error occur because it does not exist.

So can someone help to fix it? I will appreciate any explanations, links and ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error do you get? stack trace?

Comment: Actually, I get 404 error when I try to POST my login form because it tries to refer me to /login page which doesn't exist.

Comment: `/login` is actually `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter ` which is exist in spring security. You can try my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution:

(#1)You should create the bean with "customAuth" as id because spring will refer to this ID to use the `CustomAuthenticationProvider` class and just leave `@Service` without any parameter should do the trick.(You can try if you want )

(#2)After you submit the login page `in.jsp`, spring will process the info in `login-processing-url=/login` event you dont declare in your `<form-login>`. And yes spring will refer to `CustomAuthenticationProvider`. If your login was success, spring will redirect you to `default-target-url="/secret/page"`. If the login was fail,it will redirect to available permitted page.

I have change some part of your code

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    classpath:/resources/spring-context.xml
    classpath:/resources/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/sign/in" access="permitAll()" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

<form-login
    login-page="/sign/in"
    default-target-url="/secret/page"
    authentication-failure-url="/sign/in"
    password-parameter="password"
    username-parameter="username"
/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider ref="customAuth"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customAuth" class="xx.xxx.xxxx.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
</beans:beans>
```

**in.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:if test="${failed==1}">  
    <font color="red">
    Authentication failed. Wrong email/password.
    </font>
</c:if>

<form action="<c:url value='/login />'" method="POST">
    <label> E-mail </label>
    <input type="email" name="username" required><br>
    <label> Password </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in"><br>
</form>
</body>
```

The cause for 404 is because you need to define the controller with `/secret/page` and return the JSP file you need.

Hopes its help.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help and explanations. And I am sorry for a long answer. It works fine right now and I can see that that I am redirected to sign/in?failed=1, so it works(probably I made a mistake somewhere in my class that works with the database).

Comment: if you want to get a paremeter 'failed' you can add @RequestParam in method controller, and you can get the value of `failed` , welcome and gud luk :)